# Why my computer working without harddisc with livecd, but with hardisk not working - computer not response to any signals?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, computer-architecture

History of problem:

1. I formated computer (HP Pavalion Desktop).
2. When I restart computer - computer come to first screen before boot and not response to any signals (f2, f10, ESC, etc..)
3. I take out motherboad battery return after time back and power computer - result : as before
4. I disconnect wires of hard-disk and insert livecd UBUNTU to cd and power coputer: result: works without hard-disk.

What is the root of problem:

1. hard-disk broken?
2. hard-disk wires not working well?
3. BIOS?
4. other reason

How can I fix the problem?(Buy new hard disk etc...)

Thanks,

Yosef

Comment: Is the keyboard plugged in? j/k - Sounds like the hard drive is done for. But it's impossible for us to guess.

Comment: keyboard plugged in(computer working well when livecd working and hard-disk wires disconnected)

Comment: It could be many many things, and since we can't see it or touch it, it's impossible to tell you.  You're either going to have to start searching/guessing/trying and asking specific questions, or take it to someone who knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your hard drive is dead.

Try with a different drive, and then you can test if the cabling is a problem.

It's unlikely that the BIOS is causing the keyboard not to respond.

Comment: what about wires hard-drive problem? if he dead why he avoid from computer response to any signal?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

The computer is most likely hanging while trying to detect the hard drive, which may well indicate a faulty hard drive or cables.

If possible you should try replacing the hard drive and cables (but one at a time) to identify which of them is the cause.  If at all possible borrow them from either another computer or a friend; after all, you don't want to have to buy a new hard drive when it's the cable that's faulty.